# Unable to set y axis limits in ggplotly bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have the following dataset in R

```
 dataf<-data.frame("COl1"= c(5,10,15), "COl2"=c("A", "B", "C"))
```

I have created the following plot with an expanded Y axis (range between -5, 25) as follows

```
  library(ggplot2) 
  library(plotly)
  pl1 <- ggplot(data = dataf, aes(x = COl2,y = COl1 , fill = COl2)) + 
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-5,25)) + 
            geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = .35)
```

This produces a `barplot` with a y axis that is between -5, 25. Next when I try to make `dynamicticks` true the plot range collapses to the range available in the data

```
ggplotly(pl1, dynamicTicks = T, layerData = T)
```

Is there a way to retain the expanded Y axis while generating `dynamicticks` using `ggplotly` command

I have tried all other methods: `coord_cartesian`, `ylim` etc but am unable to get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `autorange` argument for `yaxis` in `plotly::layout`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dataf<-data.frame("COl1"= c(5,10,15), "COl2"=c("A", "B", "C"))

pl1<-ggplot(data = dataf, aes(x = COl2,y = COl1 , fill=COl2))+coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-5,25))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = .35)

ggplotly(pl1, dynamicTicks = T, layerData = T) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(autorange = FALSE))
```

Follow [this](https://plot.ly/r/reference) link to the reference for R plotly.